# Unexpected characters on pages with Kohana 3.3

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.3

My kohana 3.3 site contains page, which I implemented like:

```
$block_center = 'here is html form';
$this->template->block_center = array($block_center);
```

Of course, I used constructions like `View::factory(' .. ')->bind ...` - doesn't matters (result is the same).

When running site on xampp v3.0.12, It works correctly. But when I run it on hosting (Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) PHP/5.3.8) - the fun starts:
Four unexpected symbols appear on top of the page before html tag (for example: `5aeb`) and after `/html` in bottom of the page appears `0`.
When I reduce the amount of html code (in "block_center"), symbols are changing (seems like diminishing) to 2469, 22b4 and so on. And if I leave nearly ten lines of code, unexpected symbols disappear.

Can anybody help me recognize the reason of this unexpected output in kohaha? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your HTTP protocol headers. It seems like Kohana uses HTTP/1.1 by default, while your server not. Just compare `$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']` and HTTP headers (with firebug for example). Note that you can set/get protocol value with [Request::protocol()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Request#protocol) and [Response::protocol()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Response#protocol).

These links may be helpful: [1](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/5681/weird-hex-numbers-in-the-beginning-and-end-of-request-response/p1), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452284/codeigniter-strange-output-issue)